# DLL memory manager mixup

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll

I wrote an application which allows people to contribute plugins to extend the functionality. Such plugins are deployed as DLL files, which the framework picks up during runtime. Each plugin features a factory function which is called multiple times during the lifetime of the application to create objects. So far, in order to handle the ownership issue with these objects, I used a simple counting shared pointer on the returned objects so that they are destroyed whenever the last reference is removed.

However, this tends to trigger crashes on Windows since it's not unlikely to happen that the object is new'ed in the plugin DLL but later (due to a deref() call on the shared pointer) deleted in the main application - and AFAIK this malloc/free mixup is a no-no on Windows.

My current solution to this is to let deref() not call 'delete this;' directly but rather a 'release();' function which must be implemented by the plugins and calls 'delete this;'. However, it's quite annoying that each and every plugin has to implement this trivial function - I worked around this so far by providing a convenience macro plugin authors have to use. Does anybody have alternative ideas maybe?

So far, my approach is that all objects contributed by plugins is allocated in the plugins and also released there - of course, an alternative might be to let all memory be allocated in the main application (by providing a pointer to a malloc-like function to the plugins which they can then call as needed) and released there as well. The issue with this is that it's not as convenient for the plugin authors, I think.

I'd be interested in any other perspectives on this issue.

*UPDATE:* I just realized that I could reimplement operator new and operator delete on the baseclass of the objects returned by the plugins, so that new'ing them and delete'ing them will always result in function calls into the same module (so that either all allocations and free's are done in the plugin, or in the framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions. Solution one is "share more" - you can move new/delete across DLL boundaries if both sides use the same CRT DLL (/MD or /MDd in MSVC). Solution two is "share less" - let each DLL have its own C++ heap, and do not split new/delete across DLL boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that the easiest way to make sure that memory is not allocated in one DLL and released in another is this: reimplement `operator new` and `operator delete` on the base class of the objects which are returned from the plugins. In the implementations of these functions, call 'alloc' and 'free' functions (which have been passed from the main application when loading the plugin). That way, plugins can keep using 'new' and 'delete' but the memory will actually be allocated and released in the main application.

Comment: If you reimplement the new and delete operators of the base classes they will use your memory, but what about allocations done within those classes? if the plugin provider adds a string member, it will be allocated in the dll. But if you delete the object on your side, the string will be destructed on your side as well, wouldn't it? I vote for providing obj* Create() and Destroy(obj*) global functions or AddRef() and Release() ones. Sounds much safer to me.

Comment: @eran I realize this comment is about 3.5 years late, but I'm not sure I understand your concern. If I redefine `operator new` and `operator delete` on the base class and those operators will also be used if used from within derived classes. See e.g. http://ideone.com/cdNZMp which shows two calls to the custom `new`/`delete` implementations, one pair of which is caused by the `return new Derived;` within `Derived::f`.

Comment: Your example code creates an instance of the class whose `operator new` is reimplemented, so you're covered anyway. I think my concern was a derived class having a field that uses the default `new`. That class' `new` is not covered by your placement. However, now that I read this again, I think I was wrong. All memory management inside the class is safe, as long as what's created by the base class destructed by the base class, and what's created by the derived class is destructed by the derived class.

Answer (score 2):

If the DLL code is responsible for allocating objects, it should also be responsible for freeing them. I think your problem is more with the reference counting and the "delete this". If you want to go that route, why not simply implemnt the objects as COM objects? This is after all one of the main problems that COM was designed to solve!